# How to keep connection alive in Java 11 http client

Tags: java, http2, java-11, java-http-client

I'm using the Java 11 `HttpClient` with HTTP/2 and need to keep connection alive for few minutes, but the builder does not have the option to set it. Is there a way to specify this and make client keep the connection alive for some time?

Answer (score 22):

If you build a standard HttpClient e.g. using `HttpClient.newHttpClient();` by default a connection pool is created. This pool keeps the connections alive by default for 1200 seconds (20 minutes).

If you want to change the keep-alive timeout you can do so using the property `jdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout`. However the value is only read once when the class `jdk.internal.net.http.ConnectionPool` is loaded. Afterwards it can't be changed anymore.

Therefore you have to set this property for the whole JVM:

```
-Djdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout=99999
```

Or at runtime before the `ConnectionPool` class has been loaded:

```
System.setProperty("jdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout", "99999");
```

A third option is to using a file named `${java.home}/conf/net.properties` and set the property in there.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. Is there a way to configure the the pool size? Default timeout of 20 minutes is fine.

Comment: @qiGuar use the property `jdk.httpclient.connectionPoolSize` by default this property is `0` (unbound)

Comment: Let me try! So if it's unbound, it means that on every request it'll create new connection? Also, is there a documentation link for this info? thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: Oh, the pool is used only for http 1.1, not for http 2 :(

Comment: @qiGuar Did you find the documentation for this property?

Comment: @Shubham It is "documented" from source: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.net.http/share/classes/jdk/internal/net/http/ConnectionPool.java#L54-L57

Comment: You can find these properties documented on oracle's site also: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/core/java-networking.html#GUID-82A738CB-2A1C-4AC8-B9DA-C4543D398B51

Answer (score 2):

Both HTTP/2 and HTTP/1.1 connections are kept alive by default. There are some exceptions when several concurrent connections are opened to the same host - then only one of them will be kept alive.

Comment: how do you know that's the case?  is this configurable, or documented somewhere?

Comment: @liltitus27 From [the specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-6.3): “If the received protocol is HTTP/1.1 (or later), the connection will persist after the current response…” [in the absence of a Connection: close header]