# How to close HttpClient? Why there is no .close() method in the API?

Tags: java, httpclient, httpconnection

I want to use so called "new HttpClient since Java 11" `java.net.http.HttpClient`.

To me, it is *very important* to make sure that the TCP connection gets closed after an HTTP roundtrip completes, so that corresponding port gets released and resources - deallocated.

There is no `.close()` or `.disconnect()` or something like that available on the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html).

It is very weird not to have a possibility to close the connection, and it is also weird why the expected behaviour (*what is happening? is the connection getting closed automatically? when? how?*) is never documented anywhere, including [Introduction to the Java HTTP Client](https://openjdk.org/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html)
 and [Examples and Recipes](https://openjdk.org/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html)
.

Any tips?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53617574/how-to-keep-connection-alive-in-java-11-http-client may help

Comment: But why do you think this is important?

Comment: 1. Provided link doesn't help as it answers different question (although I still got some information from that post.. so, thanks); 2. Because, as I said, I want to make sure previously allocated ports/resources get released.. leaving connection, in the connection pool, by default for 20 minutes and having no way to close connection is beyond crazy.

Comment: [HttpResponse.BodySubscriber](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodySubscriber.html) talks about closing underlying connections, but there doesn't seem to be any way of explicitly doing so for now, as stated with the Holger's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, since the Java 21 LTS, the `java.net.http.HttpClient` is now `AutoCloseable`, and the [following methods have been added](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/21all-relnotes.html#JDK-8267140) to the API:

- `void close()` - closes the client gracefully, waiting for submitted requests to complete;
- `void shutdown()` - initiates a graceful shutdown, then returns immediately without waiting for the client to terminate;
- `void shutdownNow()` - initiates an immediate shutdown, trying to interrupt active operations, and returns immediately without waiting for the client to terminate;
- `boolean awaitTermination(Duration duration)` - waits for the client to terminate, within the given duration; returns true if the client is terminated, false otherwise;
- `boolean isTerminated()` - returns true if the client is terminated.

---

Two additional notes:

1. The instances returned by `HttpClient.newHttpClient()`, and the instances built from `HttpClient.newBuilder()`, provide a best effort implementation for these methods. They allow the reclamation of resources allocated by the `HttpClient` early, without waiting for its garbage collection;
2. An `HttpClient` instance typically manages its own pools of connections, which it may then reuse when necessary. Connection pools are typically not shared between `HttpClient` instances. Creating a new client for each operation, though possible, will usually prevent reusing such connections.

Answer (score 6):

This is indeed a missing feature and you’ll have to wait for Java 21 to be able to close `HttpClient` explicitly.

See bug report [JDK-8304165](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8304165), “Support closing the HttpClient by making it auto-closable”:

> Make the `java.net.http.HttpClient` implement `AutoCloseable` in order to make it possible to reclaim its resources early (selector, idle connections sitting in pools, etc...) rather than having to wait for GC to garbage collect it.

It has the status “Approved” and Fix Version 21. You can also verify with the [early access documentation of `HttpClient`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) which shows that it now implements `AutoCloseable` and therefore has a [`close` method](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html#close()) which also says “Since: 21”.

Comment: Yes, I found that link, but still decided to ask, because 1) I really couldn't imagine any (especially - new) HTTP client being implemented without `.close()`, and 2) Bug page's summary mentions "in order to make it possible to reclaim its resources early" - so, I thought it was reclaiming resources in some "later" way.. but not as later as [after 20 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53620696/1553537). Great.. introducing a lot of unnecessary and decorative JEPs, while having "new and cool" HTTP client without basic and super important `.close()` ability.. and that's since Java 11, 2018.

Comment: I know exactly how you feel. I’m waiting for a possibility to close a `MappedByteBuffer` for twenty years now. There will be an indirect solution through JEP 434, which is still in preview…