# HttpClient Object in Java 11 OpenJDK

Tags: java-11, java-http-client

I'm using Java 11 HttpClient to send request to a remote server.

I wanted to know if there is a difference on the HttpClient object when creating object in below 2 different ways

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
```

vs

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1).
    .connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(2000))
    .build();
```

For Starters,

1. There seems to be no provision to set `connectTimeout` when creating object using  `HttpClient.newHttpClient()`
2. Also, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53617574/how-to-keep-connection-alive-in-java-11-http-client), it appears a default connection pool (UNLIMITED connections) is created with `keepalive.timeout=1200` seconds only when the `HTTPCLient` object is created using `HttpClient.newHttpClient()`.

Does this not happen when it is created using the following?

```
HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1).
    .connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(connectionTimeout))
    .build()
```

I want to leverage automatic connection pool creation of Java 11 HTTPClient with my custom `keepalive.timeout=120` sec and still be able to also set `connectTimeout` value.

Please advise, TIA.

Comment: There is no correlation between the connect timeout and the keep alive timeout. The keep alive timeout only affects idle connections that sit in the pool, and can only be configured system-wide by supplying system properties on the command line (or editing the conf/net.properties file).
If you supply a different keepalive timeout via a system property on the java command line it will work for all instances of HttpClient.

Comment: Note also that we changed the default value in recent version of the JDK.
See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.net.http/module-summary.html

Comment: Hi @daniel, with `HttpClient.newHttpClient()` I do not have an option to set the 'connecttimeout` on the HttpClient object returned.  Add, if a default connectionpool still created behind the scene if I create my client object via `HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1). .connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(connectionTimeout)) .build()` ?. I do see that latest Java version has defaulted keepalive.timeout to 30s but I'm using Java 11 which defaults to 20 min which is too high and I want to set it to 2 mins

Comment: `HttpClient.newHttpClient()` is the equivalent to `HttpClient.newBuilder().build()`;
Use the `jdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout` system property on the java command to control the keep-alive timeout in the HTTP/1.1 connection pool (note that this is a system-wide setting). In Java 11 the keep alive property applies only to the HTTP/1.1 connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient.newHttpClient()` is equivalent to `HttpClient.newBuilder().build()`.
This means that it creates an `HttpClient` with default settings.

Therefore, if you need non default settings, you should use

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                              .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1). 
                              .connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(2000)) 
                              .build();
```

As for the keep alive property, as mentioned in the referenced question, you can change the default to 2 minutes with

```
-Djdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout=120
```

This will affect all `HttpClient` instances, regardless of whether you create them with `HttpClient.newBuilder()` or with `HttpClient.newHttpClient()`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can set your Keep-Alive time by using

```
-Djdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout=120
```

Or making a Static Block and set System Property

```
static{
       System.setProperty("jdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout","120");
   }
```