# Is there a way to make keep-alive setting specific to one instance of java.net.http.HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient, java-11, keep-alive, java-http-client

I know you can set keep-alive by using System property **`jdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout`**, and this value is only read once when the class jdk.internal.net.http.ConnectionPool is loaded. Afterwards, [it cannot be changed anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53617574/how-to-keep-connection-alive-in-java-11-http-client). However, this would make all instances of java.net.http.HttpClient have the same keep-alive setting. Is there a way to do this, that is specific to a single instance of the client?

One idea I had is to set headers on the request explicitly. Example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=1000
```

However, not sure if this will work or if there is a better way to override settings like this.  I was surprised to see configurations like this not available on the client builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to do this today is with a system property on the java command line. The Keep-Alive header field returned by the server is currently ignored, though there is an RFE to revisit this: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8326160. Also note that Keep-Alive is only valid for HTTP/1.1 (not for HTTP/2)